# How to globally modify variable from externalized tikz picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, latex3, tikz-external

Is it possible to update global variables from within externalized tikz picture?

I would like for global modifiers(in this case `\tl_gput_right:Nn`) to outlast the scope of tikz picture.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage [utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage {tikz}
\usepackage {xparse}

% Setup externalization.
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=images/]
\tikzset{png export/.style={external/system call/.add={}{; convert -density 300 "\image.pdf" "\image.png"}}}
\tikzset{png export}

% Declare global variable.
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \tl_clear_new:N \something
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin {document}
    \ExplSyntaxOn

        % Draw a picture and update global variable.
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw node {aaa};
            \tl_gput_right:Nn \something {AAA}
            \tl_log:N \something % Value is "AAA".
        \end{tikzpicture}

        % Print global variable afterwards.
        \tl_log:N \something % Value is "".

    \ExplSyntaxOff
\end {document}
```

I would like for last `\tl_log:N` to show value `AAA` just like it does if `externalization` part is commented-out.

Comment: The contents of the `tikzpicture` are executed in a separate document, so the main one has no “memory” of it. You'd probably need some auxiliary file which will keep the value of `\something` while the `tikzpicture` job is being executed and will be read back by the main job once that picture is finished. What exactly do you want to achieve? Perhaps knowing the goal someone might know a better option.

Comment: I am wondering about the same thing as @PhelypeOleinik and feel that your goal defeats the purpose of externalize. You may roughly think of externalize as "create a pdf in the first run and just include the pdf in the subsequent runs". Why would you want to define some new macro that gets broadcasted outside the externalized picture?

Comment: I am writing a small simulator for my C++ library. The idea is to generate several similar pictures representing the work of the library. Each picture is drawn based on the current library state and the provided input. Input is provided through function arguments, but I wanted the internal state of the library(which changes while drawing a picture) to be updated while the picture is drawn and used by the next picture. It is possible to separate drawing from variable updates, but it would duplicate a lot of same `if` statements in both places. Hope this clears my intention.

Comment: To be honest, it doesn't. You use externalize to "freeze" a tikzpicture. So why don't you just compile the first run without externalize, get all the dimensions out, and then externalize things?

Comment: Sorry, can you explain how to do the 2-pass compilation in a bit more details?
Just to clarify, I can't just calculate all and then draw. Every picture needs to draw some intermediate state.

Comment: Imagine if I am drawing array of boxes representing the array of integers. For example, on first picture I add one integer to array(so, update global variable and draw picture based on current state of that global variable), on second I  add two more(again, update previous state by adding two more integers to global variable and then draw it) and so on... Keep in mind that my case is not as trivial as just adding variable to array, it can't be separated before and while tikzpicture is on, without code duplication. Feel free to post your idea as answer, since my original request is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Phelype Oleinik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134574/phelype-oleinik) suggested in comment, I ended up writing the data from `tikzpicture` environment to external file and then reading it back when `tikzpicture` ended.

One way of doing it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage [utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage {tikz}
\usepackage {xparse}

% Setup externalization.
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=images/]
\tikzset{png export/.style={external/system call/.add={}{; convert -density 300 "\image.pdf" "\image.png"}}}
\tikzset{png export}

% Declare global variables.
\ExplSyntaxOn
    % Streams for reading and writing to file.
    \iow_new:N \output_stream
    \ior_new:N \input_stream

    \tl_clear_new:N \something
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin {document}
    \ExplSyntaxOn

        % Draw a picture and update global variable.
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw node {aaa};
            \tl_gput_right:Nn \something {AAA}
            \tl_log:N \something % Value is "AAA".

            % Store data in file to use it outside of tikzpicture.
            \iow_open:Nn \output_stream {stored_data}
            \iow_now:Nx \output_stream {\something} % You can generate \iow_now:NV variant instead of \iow_now:Nx
            \iow_close:N \output_stream
        \end{tikzpicture}

        % Read stored data from file.
        \ior_open:Nn \input_stream {stored_data}
        \ior_get:NN \input_stream \something
        \ior_close:N \input_stream

        % Print global variable afterwards.
        \tl_log:N \something % Value is now "AAA".

    \ExplSyntaxOff
\end {document}
```